# How to store cumulative output in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am using the following code to get frequency of letters in a text:

```
for s in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':
    count = 0
    for char in rawpunct.lower():
        if s == char:
            count +=1
    result = s, '%.3f' % (count*100/len(rawpunct.lower()))
    f_list.append(result)
```

And the result is :

```
['0.061', '0.012', '0.017', '0.030', '0.093', '0.016', '0.016', 
'0.049', '0.050', '0.001', '0.006', '0.034', '0.018', '0.052', '0.055',
 '0.013', '0.001', '0.041', '0.050', '0.069', '0.021', '0.007', '0.017',
 '0.001', '0.013', '0.000', '0.159']
```

but I want to store the cumulative frequencies, i.e create this list :

```
['0.061', '0.073', '0.100', '0.130' ............ ]
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This isn't the question you asked; but note that this reads through the entire text 27 times, when you could get the same result by reading through it only once. Simply create a dictionary that maps characters to sums like so: `counts = {a:0, b:0...` or, equivalently, `counts = dict((c, 0) for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '`. Then go through the text once; for every `c` in the text, do this `counts[c] += 1`. Then at the end, you can create a new cumulative list using the methods described below.

Comment: Also useful for an operation like this: [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of the one-liner :

```
original = ['0.061', '0.012', '0.017', '0.030', '0.093', '0.016', '0.016', 
'0.049', '0.050', '0.001', '0.006', '0.034', '0.018', '0.052', '0.055',
 '0.013', '0.001', '0.041', '0.050', '0.069', '0.021', '0.007', '0.017',
 '0.001', '0.013', '0.000', '0.159']

result = [sum(float(item) for item in original[0:rank+1]) for rank in xrange(len(original))]

>>> [0.061, 0.073, 0.09, 0.12, 0.213, 0.22899999999999998, 0.245, 0.294, 0.344, 0.345, 0.351, 0.385, 0.403, 0.455, 0.51, 0.523, 0.524, 0.5650000000000001, 0.6150000000000001, 0.6840000000000002, 0.7050000000000002, 0.7120000000000002, 0.7290000000000002, 0.7300000000000002, 0.7430000000000002, 0.7430000000000002, 0.9020000000000002]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `import numpy`
and then make  result  an array `results=numpy.array(result)`
and finally '`f_list=numpy.cumsum(results)`'

Answer (score 2):

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '
counts = dict.fromkeys(letters, 0)
for char in rawpunct.lower():
    try:
        counts[char] += 1
    except KeyError:
        pass
        # this character in rawpunct should not be counted!
f_list = [0]
for s in letters:
    f_list.append(f_list[-1] + counts[s])
str_list = ['{0:.3f}'.format(f) for f in f_list[1:]]
```

My `f_list` is a list of floats (it is easier to calculate sums with floats than with their string representations!). At the end I create the `str_list`, which is a list of string representations of these floats. Since you don't want to start your list with a zero, this will be removed at the end (only `f_list[1:]` is taken).

This solution is faster if your input text is long, because it reads it just once.

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(f_list) == 0:
    f_list.append(result)
else:
    f_list.append(f_list[-1] + result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f_list = [0]
for s in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ':
    count = 0
    for char in rawpunct.lower():
        if s == char:
            count +=1
    result = s, '%.3f' % (count*100/len(rawpunct.lower()))
    f_list.append(result + f_list[-1])
 f_list = list(f_list[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

My `cumsum` version, using `reduce`:

```
In [1]: x = [1,2,3]
In [2]: reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + [acc[-1] + x], x[1:], x[:1])
Out[2]: [1, 3, 6]
```

It works for empty lists, too:

```
In [3]: x = []
In [4]: reduce(lambda acc, x: acc + [acc[-1] + x], x[1:], x[:1])
Out[4]: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess rawpunct is the string cotaining your Text. I replaced it with text in my proposal:

```
from string import lowercase

text='Some arbitrary  Text with NonNSense! @#!.+-'.lower()
chmap = lowercase+' '
cooked_text = ''.join([i for i in text if i in chmap])
chdict = dict.fromkeys(chmap, 0)       #set totals-dict up 
frequencies = dict.fromkeys(chmap, 0)  #set fractions dict up

for ch in cooked_text: #toals per char
    chdict[ch] += 1

for char in chdict.keys(): #relative to text-length
    frequencies[char] = float(chdict[char]) / len(cooked_text)

frequency_list = [frequencies[char] for char in chmap]
frequency_strlist = ['%.3f' % f for f in frequency_list]
print frequency_strlist
```